# Issues rendering to texture in D3D9

Tags: c++, directx-9

I'm trying to render the world to a texture inside a hook for a game, but the image ends up [this](http://puu.sh/eM913/cc2843ee36.jpg). Since it's rendering distant objects in front of near ones, it looks like an issue with incorrect z-buffer render states, but nothing changes even when I set them before it draws.

The code inside the hook looks like this:

```
    IDirect3DSurface9 *pOrigRT;

    g_pDevice->GetRenderTarget(0, &pOrigRT);
    g_pDevice->SetRenderTarget(0, pSurf[0]);

    g_pDevice->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER, 0x00000088, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    g_pDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, D3DZB_TRUE);
    g_pDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZWRITEENABLE, true);
    g_pDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZFUNC, D3DCMP_LESSEQUAL);

    ZGameDraw(pThis);

    g_pDevice->SetRenderTarget(0, pOrigRT);

    g_pDevice->StretchRect(pSurf[0], 0, pOrigRT, 0, D3DTEXF_NONE);

    SAFE_RELEASE(pOrigRT);
```

What else could cause this effect?

Comment: I think it looks like you have problems with culling techniques: http://www.gamerendering.com/2008/11/02/basic-culling-techniques/

Comment: @andreashager Why? The issue isn't that something isn't showing, it's that objects that are behind other objects are being rendered on top of them instead of behind.